How can I test an Interactor method with async tasks in Swift in XCTest?
I am working on an app in Swift using the VIP (Clean Swift) architecture. I have an interactor that has a method triggered by the ViewController's viewDidLoad (also called viewDidLoad for convenience), it starts an asynchronous task to fetch data and then updates the UI. The UI update is done via the presenter (which is injected into the interactor).
In my test, I want to verify that the presenter’s method is called when the interactor's viewDidLoad is triggered. I’m using a mock presenter and checking if the expected methods are called. However, the methods calling the presenter have to be awaited because they run using @MainActor and I'm not sure how to await them in my tests.
Here’s a simplified version of my interactor:
protocol MyInteractorProtocol {
    func viewDidLoad()
}

class MyInteractor: MyInteractorProtocol {
    private var presenter: MyPresenterProtocol

    init(presenter: MyPresenterProtocol) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        Task {
            await fetchData()
        }
    }

    private func fetchData() async {
        // Some data fetching here
        await updateUI()
    }

    @MainActor
    private func updateUI() {
        presenter.presentData()
    }
}

And my current test:
import XCTest

final class MyInteractorTests: XCTestCase {
    func testViewDidLoadCallsPresenterUsingSleep() async throws {
        let mockPresenter = MockPresenter()
        let interactor = MyInteractor(presenter: mockPresenter)

        interactor.viewDidLoad()

        // I'm currently using sleep to wait for the async task to finish
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000) // 1 second

        XCTAssertTrue(mockPresenter.presentDataCalled)
    }

    func testViewDidLoadCallsPresenterUsingExpectation() {
        let mockPresenter = MockPresenter()
        let interactor = MyInteractor(presenter: mockPresenter)

        let expectation = expectation(description: "Presenter should call presentData")

        Task {
            interactor.viewDidLoad()
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [expectation])
        XCTAssertTrue(mockPresenter.presentDataCalled)
    }
}

The first test uses Task.sleep() to wait for async operations to finish, but I'd like to avoid this approach. In the second test, I used XCTestExpectation, but it feels hacky (and seems to lead to flaky tests).
Question: What is the correct way to test async tasks in Swift XCTest without relying on Task.sleep() or arbitrary delays? Ideally, I want the test to wait for the task to complete before performing assertions, but without hardcoded sleep durations or hacks to get it to work. Any suggestions for a better testing pattern in this case?

Your interactor's viewDidLoad should be async rather than using unstructured concurrency. Your second test function can then be marked async and then you can  get rid of the Task and use await.

@Paulw11 But I don't think I should change a method to async just for the test to work, right?

No, you should change the method to async because it should be async. It is the right design. Right now you have an async function that has no way of indicating to its caller that its work is complete. That is why you are finding it difficult to test. It should either be async or accept a completion handler which it invokes when it's async work is complete - but it doesn't make sense to combine Swift concurrency with old-style completion handlers in new code. You will still need an unstructured Task in your view controller viewDidLoad because you can't make that method async

@Paulw11 But then I'm moving the problem to my view controller's tests, where I mock the Interactor and want to confirm that the Interactor's viewDidLoad has been called. How would I solve that problem then?

When you are finding it difficult to write a test it can be a hint that you have a problem in your code design.
In this case you have a function viewDidLoad in your interactor that completes work asynchronously but does not provide any indication to its caller that that work is complete. In fact, simply looking at the signature of that function you would assume that it completes synchronously.
I would change your design so that viewDidLoad is explicitly marked async. This lets you eliminate the unstructured Task from its implementation, indicates to callers that it performs work asynchronously and gives them a way of knowing when that work is done.
You will, of course, still need a Task in the view controllers viewDidLoad because you can't make that function async.
I would also not update the UI directly from fetchData - separate those two operations.
class MyInteractor: MyInteractorProtocol {
    private var presenter: MyPresenterProtocol

    init(presenter: MyPresenterProtocol) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    func viewDidLoad() async throws {
        let someData = try await fetchData()
        await updateUI(with:someData)  
    }

    private func fetchData() async throws -> SomeDataObject {
        // Some data fetching here
        return some data
    }

    @MainActor
    private func updateUI(with someData:SomeDataObject) {
        presenter.presentData(someData)
    }
}

Now your test can just use await
func testViewDidLoadCallsPresenterUsingExpectation() async {
        let mockPresenter = MockPresenter()
        let interactor = MyInteractor(presenter: mockPresenter)

        await interactor.viewDidLoad()
        XCTAssertTrue(mockPresenter.presentDataCalled)
    }


In a comment, you asked a further question -

But then I'm moving the problem to my view controller's tests, where I mock the Interactor and want to confirm that the Interactor's viewDidLoad has been called. How would I solve that problem then?

You can do this through your mock interactor implementation. Essentially you add a property that holds a closure and you invoke that closure from your mock interactor's viewDidLoad. Something like -
class MyMockInteractor {
   public var didLoadView: (() -> Void)?

   func viewDidLoad() async throws {
        defer { didLoadView?() }
        // mock implementation if required
    }

Now you can use that in your test along with the expectation.
func testViewDidLoadCallsInteractorUsingExpectation() async {
   let mockPresenter = MyMockPresenter()
   let interactor = MockInteractor(presenter: mockPresenter)

    let vc = MyViewController()
    vc.interactor = interactor

   let expectation = expectation(description: "ViewController calls interactor")

   interactor.didLoadView = {
       expectation.fulfill()
   }

   vc.loadView()

   wait(for: [expectation])
   XCTAssertTrue(mockPresenter.presentDataCalled)
}

You could also use this approach with your original code structure, but I think that eliminating the unstructured concurrency from new code is preferable

Thanks for the answer. The only thing now is, that the problem with the test has shifted to the ViewController's tests. I'd like to confirm in the ViewController's tests that the interactor's methods have been called correctly. Using a Task there will lead to the same problem as currently in the interactor - right?

I agree with Paulw11: As a general rule, if the interactor’s method is asynchronous, then it should just be an async method (and remain within structured concurrency). You want to avoid unnecessarily baking in unstructured concurrency (where you have no way of knowing when it’s done, no way of canceling it when it is no longer needed, etc.).

@BjornB. – Regarding the view controller (where you need unstructured concurrency to bridge from the synchronous context to Swift concurrency, you have two options: 1. You could save the Task {…} in a var task: Task<Void, Error>? property (which you want, anyway, to support cancelation, etc.), and await that before performing the XCT assertions. 2. Personally, I write unit tests for things like this “interactor” (or services, or view models, or whatever), but for view controllers, I focus on UI tests, not unit tests.
